# Sum of intervals lengths from an integer vector

Tags: r, intervals

Let's say I have this integer `vector`:

```
> int.vec
 [1]  1  2  3  5  6  7 10 11 12 13
```

(created from `int.vec <- c(1:3,5:7,10:13)`)

I'm looking for a function that will return the sum of the lengths of all intervals in this vector.

So basically for `int.vec` this function will return:

```
3+3+4 = 10
```

Comment: You can use the `diff` function

Comment: will this ever not be `length(int.vec)`?

Comment: @Symbolix, that's the best answer for this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable by taking the difference of adjacent elements, check whether that is not equal to 1, get the `cumsum`, use `tapply` to get the `length`, and `sum` the output.

```
sum(tapply(int.vec,cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(int.vec) !=1)), FUN=length))
#[1] 10
```

---

Or use `table` and `sum`

```
sum(table(int.vec,cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(int.vec) !=1))))
#[1] 10
```

---

Or we `split` the "int.vec" with the grouping variable derived from `cumsum` (`split` is very fast) and get the `length` of each `list` element with `lengths` (another fast option) - contributed by @Frank

```
sum(lengths(split(int.vec, cumsum(c(0,diff(int.vec)>1)))))
```

NOTE: No packages used.  This will be helpful for identifying the individual `length` of each component (in case we needed that) by just removing the `sum` wrapper.

---

Based on further insights from @Symbolix's solution, the OP's expected output is just the `length` of the `vector`.

```
NROW(int.vec)
#[1] 10
```

can be used as well.  This will also work in case we are working with `data.frame`.  But, as I mentioned above, it seems that the OP need to identify both the `length` of each interval as well as the `length`.  This solution provides both.

Comment: Could also take advantage of the newish `lengths` function `sum(lengths(split(int.vec, cumsum(c(0,diff(int.vec)>1)))))`. I guess the downvote was because you didn't identify that the OP's desired output is the same as `length(int.vec)`

Comment: @Frank Thanks, for that.  But, I wonder `lengths` would work in crossplatform.  Last week, I was testing a forecast app (built by me) using Alteryx.  Though, I used the current version of R, `lengths`  didn't work.

Answer (score 13):

```
length(int.vec)
# 10
```

Your intervals are sequences of numbers, `x1:xn`, `x1:xm`, `x1:xp`, where the length of each vector (or interval in this case) is `n`, `m`, and `p` respectively.

The length of the whole vector is `length(x1:xn)` + `length(x1:xm)` + `length(x1:xp)`,
which is the same as `length(n + m + p)`.

---

Now, if we really are interested in the length of each individual vector of sequences, we can do

```
int.vec <- c(1:3,5:7,10:13)

## use run-length-encoding (rle) to find sequences where the difference == 1
v <- rle(diff(int.vec) == 1)[[1]]
v[v!=1] + 1
# [1] 3 3 4
```

And, as pointed out by @AHandcartAndMohair, if you're working with a list you can use [`lengths`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lengths.html)

```
int.list <- list(c(1:3), c(5:7), c(10:13))
lengths(int.list)
# [1] 3 3 4
```

Comment: Combined with this, if they used `list` instead of `c`, they would be able to use the `lengths` function to get the 3, 3, 4 vector (so obviously, `sum(lengths(int.vec))` to get the overall length.

Comment: @AHandcartAndMohair Thanks - I've added this to my answer :)

Answer (score 12):

The "cgwtools" package has a function called `seqle` that might be helpful here.

```
library(cgwtools)
int.vec <- c(1:3,5:7,10:13)
seqle(int.vec)
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:3] 3 3 4
#   values : int [1:3] 1 5 10
```

The result is a `list`, so you can just access and sum the "lengths" values with:

```
sum(seqle(int.vec)$lengths)
# [1] 10
```